# Rails 3.2 ruby 1.9.3 exception_notification in staging not able to send mail

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, exception-notification

I am applying exception notification gem for rails 3.2 application.

Following is my  code

```
gemfile

gem 'exception_notification'

config/environments/staging.rb

Rails.application.config.middleware.use ExceptionNotification::Rack,  email: {
 email_prefix: '[Exception] ',
 sender_address: %('HPAE - Error' <mymail@gmail.com> ),
 exception_recipients: %w(mamail1@gmail.com)
}
```

It runs perfectly in my local but on server in staging its not working. I am not receiving any error mails from staging.

Do I need to change my code or do any setting?

Thanks,

Comment: Have you read the requirements? `Ruby 2.0 or greater, Rails 4.0 or greater`

Comment: https://github.com/rails/exception_notification

Comment: Do you understand how emails send? Which command used by Rails?

Comment: Also you question is off-topic. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.

Comment: My problem is simple to understand i am not receiving mails from server(staging env.). Is there issue in my code or there are any  more to settings need to be done?